# How to uninstall sqoop-1.99.7 from hadoop 3.0.3 running on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop

I am trying to uninstall Sqoop-1.99.7 from Hadoop 3.0.3 running on Ubuntu 16.04.
I wasn't able to find the sqoop-template-env.sh file from the */usr/lib/sqoop-1.99.7-bin-hadoop200/conf* location. My hadoop is properly installed and if I run the start-all.sh command I can see that everything is working fine but when I installed sqoop and in the process in order to start the sqoop I had to edit the environment file of sqoop that should be present in the conf directory, I couldn't find it. Can someone please help on how can I uninstall sqoop so that I can reinstall again.

Thanks,
Ejaaz Shaik.

Comment: Well, how did you install Sqoop? Have you tried using the `find` or `locate` command for the file you want?

Comment: I believe the installation wasn't done properly for the latest version. However I did try to install the older version and it worked. And yes @cricket_007 I did try find and locate command for locating the file I needed.

Comment: You succeeded installing sqoop 1.99 on an haddop 3 cluster? Nice. What documentation did you follow?